# Increasing the label value by one on button click using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have three labels with a button and on but click i need to increment the value by 1

```
     <script>
        function incrementValue() {
            var label = document.getElementById('number');
            label.textContent = (parseInt(label.textContent, 10) || 0) + 1;
        }
</script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <table >
        <tr><td><asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="Major"></asp:Label></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td><asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text="1.0"></asp:Label></td><td></td></tr>        
        <tr><td><asp:Label ID="number" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label></td><td></td></tr>
     </table>
        <input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="click" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** to get and update the text content inside label. Then get last digit using **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**, increment and update the content.

```html
<script>
  function incrementValue() {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').textContent.match(/\d+$/)[0], 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById('number').textContent = 'major 1.0 ' + value;
  }
</script>

<label id="number">major 1.0 0</label>
<input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
```

---

It can be more simplified

```html
<script>
  function incrementValue() {
    var label = document.getElementById('number');
    label.textContent = 'major 1.0 ' + ((parseInt(label.textContent.match(/\d+$/)[0], 10) || 0) + 1);
  }
</script>

<label id="number">major 1.0 0</label>
<input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
```

---

In case the string varies then, you can do something like this

```html
<script>
  function incrementValue() {
    var label = document.getElementById('number');
    var m = label.textContent.match(/^(.*)(\d+)$/);
    label.textContent = m[1] + ((parseInt(m[2], 10) || 0) + 1);
  }
</script>

<label id="number">major 1.0 0</label>
<input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
```

---

With your own simple ternary operator

```html
<script>
  function incrementValue() {
    var label = document.getElementById('number');
    var m = label.textContent.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/);
    var value = parseInt(m[2], 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    label.textContent = m[1] + (value + 1)
  }
</script>

<label id="number">major 1.0 0</label>
<input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Increment Value" />
```

---

**UPDATE :** As per the updated question you can do

```html
<script>
  document.onkeyup = KeyCheck;

  function KeyCheck(e) {
    var key = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    if (key == 113) {
      var label = document.getElementById('number');
      var m = label.textContent.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/);
      var value = parseInt(m[2], 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      label.textContent = m[1] + (value + 1)
    }
  }
</script>

<label id="number">major 1.0 0</label>
```

Comment: `m[1]` holds first captured group value which is the string.... `parseInt(m[2], 10)` , where `m[2]` is second captured group which is the number........... `(parseInt(m[2], 10) || 0)` , if parseint returns `NaN`, which is falsy value so `0` will returned (logical short circuit evaluation) .... atlast adding `1`  to the result and concatenating it with the captured group string

Comment: @kavithavemula : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation

Comment: @kavithavemula `(parseInt(label.textContent, 10) || 0)` , if the statement before `||` returned any `falsy` value then it `(parseInt(label.textContent, 10) || 0)` results `0`(which is second statement) else the result of first statement

Comment: @kavithavemula `10` is used to  treat it as decimal number

Comment: @kavithavemula [_check documentation __An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string. Specify 10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans. Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to 10.___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters)

Comment: @kavithavemula in input element??

Comment: @kavithavemula : it's better to add as a new question.... with your code , that you have tried :)

Comment: @kavithavemula do you want to decrement? and which eleemnt should have the keydown handler?

Comment: @kavithavemula : don't change the entire question , either add it as update or add a new question

Comment: @kavithavemula : binding keyup event to entire document, and checking the `keyCode` to check which key is pressed..... based on that updating the text..... where `113` is keyCode for `f2`

Comment: @kavithavemula : glad to help :)

Comment: @kavithavemula : sorry I'm not familiar with it

Comment: @kavithavemula : glad to help you :)

Comment: @kavithavemula : check ck editor documentation... there will be details about events...

Comment: where can i found the documentation already it is integrated in my project using ajax tool kit

Comment: @kavithavemula : may be here : http://docs.ckeditor.com/ , please avoid non-related comments on the answer :)

Comment: k thank you i will check it there in that documentation

Comment: the javascript code provided by you works fine for me but now there was a small problem in it can you please help me out i tried a lot but i could not come up with solution the question was posted by me here 37655693 could you please help me out